# How do i turn this into a callback and also export the value it produces

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, node-modules

I am trying to export the value of a database check from this module to another module, but this code gets run last, so it is undefined when i need the value

So i want other codes to wait for it before running,

i tried making it a promise but it still only runs after others, please help

```
function userfind(iemail) {
  // let value = '';
  const query = {
    // give the query a unique name
    name: 'fetch-user',
    text: 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1',
    values: [iemail],
  };

  pool.query(query, (error, results) => {
    console.log(results.rowCount);
    let val = '';
    if (error) {
      val = 'false';
      return val;
    }
    if (results.rowCount > 0) {
      val = 'true';
      return val;
    }
    if (results.rowCount === 0) {
      val = 'false';
      console.log('func: ', val);
      return val;
    }
  });
```

Comment: You can't. Export a Promise instead, and the other module can get the value from the Promise.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a promise that can be consumed later, like so:

```js
function userfind(iemail) {
  // let value = '';
  const query = {
    // give the query a unique name
    name: 'fetch-user',
    text: 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1',
    values: [iemail],
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query(query, (error, results) => {
      console.log(results.rowCount);
      let val = '';
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
      if (results.rowCount > 0) {
        val = 'true';
        resolve(val);
      }
      if (results.rowCount === 0) {
        val = 'false';
        console.log('func: ', val);
        resolve(val);
      }
    });
  })
}

// Some other code:

userfind('some@email.com')
  .then(val => {
    // do something with val
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // handle error
  })
```

Comment: Note that `pool.query` likely returns promise when callback not used making this an anti-pattern approach

Comment: Not many db driver packages around any more that don't support promises

Comment: That's a good point - this shows more of a generic approach to promisifying things